# UITableView section footer height in relation to accessibility text size

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can't figure out how to set UITableView section footer height in relation to system text chosen in accessibility.

Ideas?

Comment: @matt probably you're not idea what I'm speaking. Second your opinion is not possible set text in section footer?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: set -1 in heightForFooterAtIndexPath